# Show/Hide element on jquery Fancy Box close event

Tags: jquery, fancybox, jquery-events

I want to `Show()` an element when my jquery FancyBox is closed. How can I do this?

Is there any `close` event?

```
var urlOfferDetails = $('#OfferDetails').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlOfferDetails,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'offerID': productCode, 'providerId': providerCode },
        closeBtn: 'true',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $.fancybox(
            {
                'href': '#offerPopup',
                'content': data,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'autoScale': false,
                'overlayShow': true,
                'type': 'iframe'
            });
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('.scrollup').hide();
        },
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a afterClose key to fancybox as shown below, it will be called once fancybox is closed. Refer [docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

```
   var urlOfferDetails = $('#OfferDetails').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: urlOfferDetails,
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 'offerID': productCode, 'providerId': providerCode },
        closeBtn: 'true',
        success: function (data) {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $.fancybox(
            {
                'href': '#offerPopup',
                'content': data,
                'hideOnOverlayClick': false,
                'hideOnContentClick': false,
                'autoScale': false,
                'overlayShow': true,
                'type': 'iframe',
                'afterClose' : function(){console.log("FancyBox Closed");}
            });
        },
        error: function (req, status, error) {
        },
        complete: function () {
            $("#loading").hide();
            $('.scrollup').hide();
        },
    });
```

Comment: Thanks. Also could you plz tell me if I have more than one fancy box and I do some action will this piece of code affect all of them?

Comment: this only affects the fancybox where afterClose is specified.